# drag and drop HTML with two list. the second list imitate what happen in the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have two list and each list have an elements link to the other list such as

```
list A     List B
1          1
2          2
3          3
```

each same number is link to other
What I want is that each time I move with drag and drop an elements inside the first list, it automatically drag and drop an other elements at the same place in the other list. 
If I drag the 3 on the first list just before the 1, i want the other list to do the same automatically just like this:

```
3          3
1          1
2          2
```

I’m using: http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/ but I can use any other things
I'm trying to search on the web but I guess the fact I couldn’t name the things in a simple way, didn’t help me to find the right things.

Comment: Do you have the drag and drop working? Seems like it would be easy to modify that to move other elements, along with the one being dragged. Need to see more code to help...